# Why is TeX ignoring texmf.cnf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmf

I got the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]
```

while compiling a TikZ path containing ~10,000 points. So i decided to increase this memory limit of TeX. I edited the /usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf file. Now it contains the following lines:

```
main_memory.latex = 30000000

main_memory.pdflatex = 30000000

main_memory.xelatex = 30000000
```

But the pdflatex or xelatex dies with the same error, and it says, that the main memory size is still 3,000,000. I was searching for other `texmf.cnf` files, and there is one here: `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`. But it's just a link, the changes what i made, appeared also in that file. So why does TeX ignore it?

I'm using TeX Live 2010/Arch Linux.

Comment: did you regenerate the formats?

Comment: that's the solution. i run fmtutil instead fmtutil-sys. now it works, and i'm able to compile the large tikzpicture. thank you!

Comment: @Taco: Please add it as an answer now so that vizipok can accept it and conclude the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you change the array size values in `texmf.cnf`, the formats need to be regenerated, since these values are stored into the formats themselves. The command used to recreate the formats is:

```
fmtutil-sys --all
```

Comment: On standard TeX Live systems there's a "local" `texmf.cnf` file located in `/usr/local/texlive/<year>/` where site changes to variables can be made without touching the main file that could be rewritten during updates. Is there the possibility also on "packaged" TeX Live distributions such as the one for ArchLinux?

Comment: i don't have that file, in this distribution the local tree is /usr/share/texmf/, and the regulary updated tree is /usr/share/texmf-dist/. and texmf.cnf exist only in the former.