# Increase TeX capacity, as non-root

Tags: texmf, linux

I have a LaTeX document that uses many long pgf paths, and thus compiles only if one increases the TeX "capacity" by setting `save_size=50000` in `texmf.cnf`.

Unfortunately I cannot change the system-wide `texmf.cnf` directly as I have no root access on my work machine (OpenSuSE 11.3). Is there a way to use a user-defined `texmf.cnf` that overrides the limits?

> **Disclaimer**: as pointed out by Juan Navarro in the comments, errors of the form *tex capacity exceeded* are often caused by syntax errors. Even if you get that error message, 99% of the times the correct thing to do is **not** increasing capacity.

Comment: Maybe for some reason you really need to do this but, in my experience, you *hardly ever* need to "increase LaTeX capacity"; often this just means that there is an error on your `.tex` file that you should try to solve. Comment out portions of your code until it works, and try to determine what causes the "LaTeX capacity exceeded" error.

Comment: I think I *do* need to increase LaTeX capacity. On a computer on which I do have root access, my document compiles if I set `save_size = 50000` rather than 5000. I am including a pgf path with some 200 points with `\input{}` multiple times --- or maybe is there a smarter way to do that?

Comment: @Federico, this is another question...

Comment: Ok, but I don't think that's the main point - let's say that the question is 'I have some odd latex file that compiles only if I set `save_size=50000` --- but alas, I am not root. How can I make this change?'

Comment: I see a `-save-size=N` option in my `pdflatex` command (MiKTeX 2.9). Does that help?

Comment: On my distro (texlive 2009) this command-line switch has no effect (the document still fails to compile and complains that `save_size=5000` is not enough), and it is not mentioned in the docs either.

Comment: @Federico, Indeed you might then need to do this. I only wanted to add that disclaimer for people stumbling with this question while googling how to "increase LaTeX capacity".

Comment: You *can* increase the memory size locally by editing a local `texmf.cnf`.  The trick is that you need to regenerate the formats using `fmtutil` after changing the sizes.  This answer [Memory settings with MacTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24753/2693) outlines the steps for doing this with root access; you can follow the same steps for modifying a local `texmf.cnf` provided you use `fmtutil` instead of `fmutil-sys`.

Comment: @Alan I'm not really sure if it's necessary to always regenerate the formats using `fmtutil` after changing the sizes. If you read the part 3 of `texmf.cnf`, you can  find "If a change here appears to be ignored, try redumping the format file
with fmtutil-sys" and  "main_memory is relevant only to initex, extra_mem_* only to non-ini. Thus, have to redump the .fmt file after changing main_memory; to add to existing fmt files, increase extra_mem_* ". What do you think about theses sentences ?

Comment: @Altermundus I seem to recall during my testing of the answer I referenced, that running `fmtutil` was necessary. This seems to be confirmed also by this question [Why is TeX ignoring texmf.cnf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23584/2693).  But since this is something that most of us do very rarely, if at all, there may well be details that I've overlooked. I don't think that regenerating the formats will cause any problems otherwise.  The only issue is that any updates that require rebuilding formats in the root version won't be reflected with a locally built set of formats.

Comment: @Alan Yes I read the link but I'm not really sure because when I compile the pgfmanual, I use the Makefile of the sources and this file uses a texmf.cnf local. A lot of sizes are changed and I don't regenerate the fmt. It will be interesting to know exactly what we need to do and in which case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same requirement when I worked with pgfplots - and I found a way.

The resulting steps have made their way into the pgfplots manual, compare the pdf at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

For your convenience, I post a copy of the section about TeX-Live here, it will probably answer your question:

6.2.2    TEXLive or similar installations
For Unix installations, one needs to adjust config files. This can be done as follows:

1. Locate texmf.cnf on your system. On my Ubuntu installation, it is in
     `/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`.
2. Either change `texmf.cnf` directly, or copy it to some convenient place. If you copy it, here is how to
     proceed:

   keep only the changed entries in your local copy to reduce conflicts. TEX will always read all   config files found in its search path.

   Adjust the search path to find your local copy. This can be done using the environment variable `TEXMFCNF`. Assuming your local copy is in`~/texmf/mytexcnf/texmf.cnf`, you can write

   ```
       `export TEXMFCNF=~/texmf/mytexcnf:`
   ```

   to search first in your directory, then in all other system directories.
3. You should change the entries

```
       main_memory = n
       extra_mem_top = n
       extra_mem_bot = n
       max_strings = n
       param_size = n
       save_size = n
       stack_size = n
```

The log­file usually contains information about the parameter which needs to be enlarged.

An example of this config file thing is shown below. It changes memory limits.

1. Create the file `~/texmf/mytexcnf/texmf.cnf` (and possibly the paths as well).

```
       % newly created file ~/texmf/mytexcnf/texmf.cnf:
       % If you want to change some of these sizes only for a certain TeX
       % variant, the usual dot notation works, e.g.,
       % main_memory.hugetex = 20000000
       main_memory = 230000000 % words of inimemory available; also applies to inimf&mp
       extra_mem_top = 10000000      % extra high memory for chars, tokens, etc.
       extra_mem_bot = 10000000      % extra low memory for boxes, glue, breakpoints, etc.
       save_size = 150000     % for saving values outside current group
       stack_size = 150000      % simultaneous input sources
       %  Max number of characters in all strings, including all error messages,
       %  help texts, font names, control sequences. These values apply to TeX and MP.
       % pool_size = 1250000
       %  Minimum pool space after TeX/MP's own strings; must be at least
       %  25000 less than pool_size, but doesn't need to be nearly that large.
       % string_vacancies = 90000
       %  Maximum number of strings.
       % max_strings = 100000
       %  min pool space left after loading .fmt
       % pool_free = 47500
```

1. Run texhash such that TEX updates its `~/texmf/ls-R database`.
2. Create the environment variable `TEXMFCNF` and assign the value `~/texmf/mytexcnf:` (including the
     trailing `:` !). For my linux system, this can be done using by adding

   `export TEXMFCNF=~/texmf/mytexcnf:`

   to `~/.bashrc`.

Unfortunately, TEX does not allow arbitrary memory limits, there is an upper bound hard coded in the
executables.

Comment: And running `fmtutil` with the new `texmf.cnf` isn't necessary?

Comment: I have never run `fmtutil`. Does texhash run `fmtutil`? I have always used `texhash`. But: I always used my user privileges, which are essentially neither root nor sudo.

Comment: No, `texhash` doesn't rebuild formats, it just updates the static ls-R databases.

Comment: Wonderful - this works, and seems a "clean" solution. I confirm that I needed no `fmtutil` and no `texhash` either, just the file and the environment variable.