# TeX capacity exceeded with glossary package

Tags: errors, glossaries

My document contains many thousands of glossary items. When compiling with XeLaTeX, about 1/8 of the way through the document, it reports:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
\@glolist@ ...},{13586},{9406},{4539},{12811},{179
                                                  51},{5831},{1047},{14948},
```

- The numbers you see above are ones placed in `#1` of `\newglossaryentry{#1}{#2}`. These unique numbers are assigned to each entry for convenience.
- I have successfully compiled short tests of the document, which only used 1% of the full content.
- The resulting `.glo` file is about 1 MB in size.

Could this be the result of some error on my part or am I giving TeX too much work to do?

Update:

I have followed the instructions below (edited `texmf.cnf` and running 
`fmtutil-sys --all`. This has allowed me to compile an additional portion of the book, but no matter the settings I add, I can't go beyond 5/8 of the way through.

A compile with `extra_mem_top.xelatex = 30000000` and `extra_mem_top.xelatex = 50000000` both result in:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=3186676].
```

Update:

I have done the following:

```
$ kpsewhich texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf
$ nano /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf
```

To the `texmf.cnf` file, following instructions at [Increase TeX capacity, as non-root](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27529/increase-tex-capacity-as-non-root), I added:

```
main_memory = 230000000
extra_mem_top = 10000000
extra_mem_bot = 10000000
save_size = 150000
stack_size = 150000

main_memory.xelatex = 30000000
extra_mem_top.xelatex = 30000000
```

After this, I tried:
- `fmtutil-sys --all`, then compiling `xelatex file.tex`.
- `fmtutil --all`, then compiling `xelatex file.tex`.
- `fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex`, then compiling with `xelatex file.tex`.
- `texhash`, then compiling with `xelatex file.tex`.

All of these resulted in no changes in results. I still get:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=3186676].
```

Comment: It is quite possible that TeX runs out of memory with huge glossary files, as it has to create a few control sequences for each entry. You should mention what operating system and TeX distribution you're using, in order somebody is able to tell you how to enlarge TeX memory.

Comment: I am using Debian 6 with TeX Live 2011 installed from www.tug.org/texlive/.

Comment: You can try enlarging also the `main_memory` as explained in my edited answer.

Comment: Have you defined all your glossary entries in the preamble or are there some defined in the document? If the latter, that could be a contributing factor, see [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming nothing is wrong with your code, you need to increase the memory TeX is allowed. Take a look [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-540006.6) for advice on how to do that.

What to do depends on the distribution you're using, and what OS you're on. This determines where the texmf.cnf file is, which you'll need to alter.

On TeXLive 2011, it is `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf`. Following alterations to this file, run

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

in a terminal.

Comment: The input stack size is currently 3,000,000. Assuming I made it only 1/8 of the way through, does that mean I should increase the memory to 24,000,000? If this number is set too high, is that likely to create some problems for my computer? I am using Debian.

Comment: It's not likely to cause you any issues at that number. There's a lot of advice in the file itself. Are you using TeXLive from the Debian package manager? I can add some detail above if I know.

Comment: No, I downloaded and installed it using the TeX Live network installer.

Comment: In that case the one to alter is `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf`.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No, it is no compiling more of the document, but I can't get it to compile more than 5/8 of the file. I've updated my original most with additional details.

Comment: Add memory to all the fields and see what happens. Remember to run fmtutil-sys.

Comment: And run it with `all`.

Comment: I adjusted the file so all settings were set to 30000000 and ran `fmtutil-sys --all`. This brought no change.

Comment: Hmm. This is a pickle! The next step is to show us the packages and macros you're using. Are you using lots of pgfplots? If that's the case, then externalise them (I can provide the keys to do that).

Comment: It is solved. I found this way: as the error says `pool size=3186676`, I added lines with large numbers for `pool_size` and `pool_size.xlatex` to the `texmf.cnf` file. Then , it reported not enough main memory, so I added `main_memory` and `main_memory.xetex`. Then , it reported not enough hash, so I added `hash_extra` and `hash_extra.xetex`. Finally, it compiles.

Answer (score 9):

You can try editing the secondary `texmf.cnf` file

```
sudo nano $(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)
```

(use your favorite text editor, for instance `gedit`, instead of `nano`). In the file that opens, append

```
extra_mem_top.xelatex = 20000000
main_memory.xelatex = 20000000
```

Save the file and run

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex
```

Then try compiling again. While modifying the first parameter doesn't generally require rebuilding formats, modifying the second does. It's the main memory that TeX (XeTeX) uses for the pool (names for control sequences).