# Am I over exerting the glossaries package?

Tags: packages, glossaries

As per the MWE below, I am using the `glossaries` package to handle the automation of values being inserted into text.

- This is useful when trends and discussions/conclusions don't change but values are a pain to replace upon updating
- This also is highly customizable to preform comparisons (max search) and simple math.
- values exported from analysis programs can easily be scripted into the observed `\newglossaryentry{}` entries and imported making for easy dynamic updates

As can be observed below, the creation of the glossary entries require a description, which is a bit of a waste of memory because what this example (being minimal) can't show, is that for thousands of entries, `glossaries` returns memory size limit problems.

Is there a more direct way to import externally saved values into my document, other than `glossaries`.

Note:  at this time, Lua scripted options are not solution I could maintain but if it is the only option, I would welcome this as a starting point for my foray into `LuaTex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nogroupskip,toc,acronym,indexonlyfirst]{glossaries} % must come after href   
\usepackage{scrwfile}%http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#glsnewwriteexceeded

\newglossary[datag]{data}{datat}{datan}{Data}

\makeindex % activate index-making
\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Control-Control}{ type={data},  name={1}, description={1} }
\newglossaryentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition1}{ type={data},  name={0.86}, description={0.86} }
\newglossaryentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition2}{ type={data},  name={0.83}, description={0.83} }

\begin{document}
    Testing glossary for values \gls{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Control-Control}, \gls{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition2}, \gls{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition2}
    No need to run a builder of makeindex because I have no intention of creating a summary list.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `datatool` (never used it so far) designed for this? By the way, the `glossaries` and `datatool` package were both written by Nicola Talbot

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I have never stumbled across this package before. I will investigate `datatool` right away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using `glossaries` is overkill here. It's a heavy-weight package because it's designed for such a wide-range of purposes (regular terms, abbreviations, symbols, plurals, user-defined additional information, etc). The `datatool` package is also heavy-weight, and again I think using that would be excessive for your requirements. If you're only interested in storing and looking up values by reference, then here's a simpler alternative that uses [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\newentry}[2]{%
  \ifcsdef{@entry@#1}%
  {\GenericError{}{Entry `#1' already defined}{}{}}%
  {\csdef{@entry@#1}{#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\entry}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{@entry@#1}%
  {\csuse{@entry@#1}}%
  {\GenericError{}{Entry `#1' not defined}{}{}}%
}

\newentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Control-Control}{1}
\newentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition1}{0.86}
\newentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition2}{0.83}

\begin{document}

Testing values
\entry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Control-Control},
\entry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition1},
\entry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition2}.

\end{document}
```

The `\newentry` command defines a control sequence used to store the relevant value. The `\entry` command accesses the stored information. The `etoolbox` command `\ifcsdef` checks if the control sequence has already been defined. `\GenericError` is part of the LaTeX kernel that prints an error message.

If you want to further cut down the resources your document requires, you can skip `etoolbox` and just use LaTeX kernel commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\newentry}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{@entry@#1}%
  {\@namedef{@entry@#1}{#2}}%
  {\GenericError{}{Entry `#1' already defined}{}{}}%
}

\newcommand*{\entry}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{@entry@#1}%
  {\GenericError{}{Entry `#1' not defined}{}{}}%
  {\@nameuse{@entry@#1}}%
}

\makeatother 

\newentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Control-Control}{1}
\newentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition1}{0.86}
\newentry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition2}{0.83}

\begin{document}

Testing values
\entry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Control-Control},
\entry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition1},
\entry{d.ControlRatio_Pooled_Classification_Stimulant-Condition2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Before I spend a lot of time changing over my extensive document dependency that follows the structure above, I would be I am curious to know if you are aware of any memory restrictions in (or other pros and cons) in implementing this elegant solution with either the base kernel commands vs `etoolbox`? My primary concern is running out of memory. I never posted a question about this, or was able to solve it from the other posted question, but my MWE had a bit of maneuvering in the background to avoid out of memory errors when my raw data imports were tens of thousands of entries.

Comment: Outside of the memory concern, the pros/cons I guess I meant is, if I have already had to use the etoolbox package, it is still taking up a greater amount of overhead to use your first solution?

Comment: @EngBIRD If you're already loading the `etoolbox` package, then I don't think there's a significant difference in using the first method over the second. `\csuse` does marginally more than `\@nameuse` as it uses the conditional `\ifcsname` which `\@nameuse` doesn't, but I don't think there's much in that. I think it might be worth seeing if you can cut down on non-essential packages or use a light-weight class. Also, if you haven't already, have a look at [Component's of (La)TeX's Memory Usage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26208/components-of-latexs-memory-usage).

Comment: For completeness, I should mention that the memory error I was trying to avoid was similar to that described:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35393/tex-capacity-exceeded-with-glossary-package but this solution failed to work.  However the comment that links to documentation:  "Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment" provides details that likely is the root of my problem of memory with `glossaries`.  Would you be able to tell me if `\newentry{}{}` is subject to the same preamble sensitivity?  Thanks.

Comment: @EngBIRD No, those issues shouldn't affect `\newentry`. Those drawbacks arise to compensate for documents where there's a glossary (or list of acronyms, etc) in the front matter. Since you said you're not interested in that, I don't see a problem with using `\newentry` within the `document` environment. You'll get an error if you attempt to use an entry before it's been defined, but then you just need to move `\newentry` to just before the first instance where it's used. I don't know how much it will help to undefine an entry when you no longer need it.