# What is `hugetex`? Does it even exist?

Tags: texmf.cnf

The file texmf.cnf contains the bit

> % If you want to change some of these sizes only for a certain TeX
>
> % variant, the usual dot notation works, e.g.,
>
> % main_memory.hugetex = 20000000

I can't find any other reference to `hugetex` in my full `texlive` distribution.  Is hugetex just something that's made up?  If not, what is it?

Comment: That's just by way of example. In the olden times it could be made.

Comment: Too bad that it can't anymore.....

Comment: Why not? You can, if you want.

Comment: I found this: https://sites.google.com/site/ifarwf/home/how-to-increase-your-latex-memory. The guy apparently used it.

Comment: @egreg : where do I find it?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner : yes, but one would have to first generate hugetex somehow....

Comment: Apparently in MiKTeX 1.11 (1998), `hugetex.exe` was an alias for `tex.exe --mem-max=20000000` (see https://www.ndsu.edu/fileadmin/math/Home_Page/Resources/Tex_and_LaTeX/Tex_and_LaTeX_Bibliography_and_templates/miktex.pdf, probably other versions as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `texmf.cnf` file you can find lines such as

```
TEXINPUTS.pdflatex      = .;$TEXMF/tex/{latex,generic,}//
```

or

```
TEXINPUTS.lualatex      = .;$TEXMF/tex/{lualatex,latex,luatex,generic,}//
```

This means that, when a binary is called with the name `pdflatex` (the binary itself will be `pdftex`), the variable `TEXINPUTS` will be set to the stated value; a different value will be used if the binary is called with the name `lualatex` (and the binary will be `luatex`).

The binaries are set up so that, if you make a symbolic link to them, they'll use the format according to the name of the symbolic link and the variables as set in `texmf.cnf` according to the same name or the “non dotted one”.

For instance, there is only

```
BIBINPUTS = .;$TEXMF/bibtex/bib//
```

which will be used by all binaries linked to the `kpathsea` library (it is of course only relevant for `bibtex`, `bibtex8` and `bibtexu`).

If you want to have a `hugetex` binary, you need to add memory settings such as

```
main_memory.hugetex = 20000000
```

and optionally set other variables such as `TEXINPUTS`. Then you make a symbolic link to the desired engine, say `pdftex` or `tex`, called `hugetex` and make a format (see the documentation of TeX Live for how to do this).

Where should these settings be added? To the top `texmf.cnf`, which you find the location of by issuing `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`. On my system this shows

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf.cnf
```

because this is the first `texmf.cnf` file read in and later named alike files will not override already set values.

Nowadays this is not very important, because one can add memory almost at will with different methods (see [TeX capacity exceeded with glossary package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35393/tex-capacity-exceeded-with-glossary-package) for instance) without the need of a specially tailored engine. In the past, having `hugetex` could be a life saver for particular applications.