# Increasing the size of the memory: not all files are built successfully

Tags: errors, memory

I am trying to compile a large file which contains a tikz picture with more data points than tex can handle.

Following the questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23584/14) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35393/14) I set to increase the capacity of tex by changing the file `texmf.cnf` in my path /usr/local/texlive/2012. I included the line

```
main_memory = 10000000
```

and on terminal I run

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

The problem is that this memory is not enough, and numbers bigger than that don't finish the fmtutil run properly. I get the error

```
 fmtutil: Error! Not all formats have been built successfully.
```

To give a better idea of where the problem is coming from, if I only include in the file `texmf.cnf` the lines

```
main_memory.latex = 15000000
main_memory.pdflatex = 15000000
```

then these are the files which are not properly built:

```
This is a summary of all `failed' messages:
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=latex -progname=latex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *latex.ini' failed
`pdftex -ini  -jobname=pdflatex -progname=pdflatex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdflatex.ini' failed
```

How can I increase the size of the memory beyond 10000000? Am I doing anything wrong?

(BTW, I am running texlive 2012 on a mac)

Comment: Maybe externalizing the large TikZ drawing first might help for the rest?

Comment: Can you try issuing the command shown on the last line and report the error message? You may try increasing `extra_mem_top` and `extra_mem_bot`, which doesn't require rebuilding formats.

Comment: @percusse Not sure what you mean by that... If you are saying I should try and compile the tikz file separately, then it wouldn't help because the tikz picture is all I am trying to compile (that's all that my .tex file has). If that's not what you mean, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Ah OK. I thought large file and TikZ drawing are different things that need to be compiled together.

Comment: @egreg: I understand what you say about `extra_mem_top` and `extra_mem_bot` and I will try that, thanks. I am not sure what you mean by "command shown on the last line", though...

Comment: @Vivi `pdftex -ini  -jobname=pdflatex -progname=pdflatex -translate-file=cp227.tcx "*pdflatex.ini"` (the double quotes protect the `*` from shell expansion).

Comment: @egreg I had no idea that was a command... Here is the error: Ouch---my internal constants have been clobbered!---case 14

Comment: On my system the maximum value for `main_memory` is 12435455

Comment: @egreg I ran fmtutil with extra_mem_top, extra_mem_bot and main_memory all set to 12435455 and it all went OK, cheers. That improves things, though it is still not enough for even 2/3 of my file. I guess I will have to reduce the number of data points.

Comment: @Vivi You may try using `lualatex`: the result should not be very different and the program dynamically allocates memory.

Comment: @Vivi First, for extending `extra_mem_top` and `extra_mem_bot` you don't need to run `fmtutil`. Setting them in `texmf.cnf` should suffice. You can also set environment variables of the same name (might be system dependent though). Secondly, `12435455` isn't the maximum by far for those two. I use `230000000` (beware of large process memory consumption).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that increasing `main_memory` is the solution: the default value is very near to the maximum (which depends also on other parameter, on my system the maximum seems to be 12435455), so you get at most a 25% increase in memory.

The parameters to play with are `extra_mem_top` and `extra_mem_bot`. The former is for "small objects", the latter for "complex" ones, such as boxes.

For example, in the main `texmf.cnf` we find

```
% ConTeXt needs lots of memory.
extra_mem_top.context = 2000000
extra_mem_bot.context = 4000000
```

so the first suggestion is to set, in the local `texmf.cnf` file located in `/usr/local/texlive/2012`,

```
% Add memory to pdflatex
extra_mem_top.pdflatex = 2000000
extra_mem_bot.pdflatex = 4000000
```

Setting these values doesn't require to rebuild the formats, as is the case for `main_memory`.

An alternative is to use `lualatex`, which allocates memory in dynamic fashion. The result shouldn't be very different to what's obtained with `pdflatex` (some small changes are possible, because LuaTeX uses slightly different hyphenation algorithms, for instance).

Comment: the extra memory didn't seem to help much (but then again, I could have kept trying higher numbers). The luatex option, though, worked. I never really understood what luatex was or what it did, and I didn't know how to use it. It compiled the document using all data points without problem! I truly appreciate your help :)

Comment: If you want to increase memory as a non-root user, you can follow the instructions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27529/increase-tex-capacity-as-non-root/27586#27586 . However, the effect is indeed limited.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the memory by `XeLaTeX` to the biggest?

Comment: @Y.zeng Did you try replacing `pdflatex` with `xelatex`?

Comment: Yes. May you tell me how to see the maximum of `main_memory`, `extra_mem_top.pdflatex` and `extra_mem_bot.pdflatex`?